# Setting up a second computer with SSH keys once you've turned off password access

Tags: openssh

I'm new to managing Linux servers. After some research and study, I was able to generate SSH keys on my laptop and use those keys to successfully log into a new server that I'd just set up. Great. Then I logged into the server and turned off password access, so I could *only* log on using those SSH keys from the laptop. Check. That particular procedure is documented over and over again on the internet, so it seems like a pretty standard workflow. And it worked flawlessly.

Now I'd like to give another computer (my desktop) the ability to access that server as well. From what I've read, it seems like best practice is to generate a new pair of SSH keys on that desktop computer that are distinct from the ones on the laptop. Makes sense.  But, since I can't use a password to log in to the server from the desktop computer, there's no way to upload that desktop computer's public key to the server. In other words, I can't repeat the workflow that was successful on laptop with the desktop.

What's the generally accepted best practice to solving this problem? Should I log onto the server from the laptop with the SSH keys and briefly turn password access back on so that I can upload the new public key from my desktop computer, then turn password access off again? Or should I find some way to copy the public key from the desktop computer to the laptop computer, then use the laptop to copy that desktop public key to the server? Would there be some permissions (or other) problems with a copy-the-key workflow like that? Or is there another, better way to accomplish this that I'm not thinking of?

I feel that I'm missing something obvious here. For as many times as the prior workflow was documented around the net, this particular problem seems to have far fewer answers.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your desktop's public key to your laptop, and then install the key on the server from the laptop.  It's just a file, so permissions are not critical when copying to the laptop.  Name the file `desktop_id_rsa.pub` or something similar.

The only critical step is installing the key on the server.  It's always wise to make a backup first:

```
laptop> ssh server 'cp -vp .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys.safety'
laptop> ssh server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < desktop_id_rsa.pub
```

It's important to have **two** greater-than signs, `>>` to ensure that you are **appending** to the `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: at Jim L. - Thanks for the answer. I stumbled upon much the same information after digging around a little more on my own. After I created the new keys on the desktop, I used a USB key to copy the new desktop public key to my laptop. Then I catted the file to the terminal, copied it, then logged into the server from the laptop. I opened ~/.ssh/authorized_keys with nano and pasted the key into a separate line. Obviously, this is another way of doing cat >> that you suggested. Both work. Thanks for the time.